# how many ways can one partition ten students into two teams of size five?

Tags: combinatorics

Is that the same as the ways can one select a team of five students out of ten students which is ten choose two or I misunderstand this point

Comment: It is half of the 10 choose 5 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting one team of five is $10 \choose 5$, not $10 \choose 2$.  Then the other five form the other team.  You probably don't care which set of five forms the first team, so need to divide by $2$ because you have counted each partition twice.

Comment: could you please explain how I counted them twice?

Comment: You choose ABCDE for one team, leaving FGHIJ for the other.  Another time you choose FGHIJ for one team, leaving ABCDE.  These are separate cases of the $10 \choose 5$ but result in the same two teams.

Comment: I didn't get it, if we consider a smaller version of the problem let's say we wanna select  2 teams each consist of 2 so (ABCD) (AB) (AC) (AD) (BC) (BD) (DC) thats for one team  but for 2 teams I don't understand what will happen

Comment: Yes, there are six ways to choose two people out of four.  If you want to divide the four into two pairs, picking AB leaves CD and picking CD leaves AB.  There are only three sets of two pairs out of four people because each division has been counted twice-(AB+CD),(AC+BD), (AD+BC)$

Comment: got it thank you but also why this could be answer as 9 choose 4

Comment: If you look at my last comment you just choose one person to put with A, so you get $3 \choose 1$ ways to split into pairs.  The idea is that by choosing A first you don't double count.  Now fill out A's team and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

The oldest student $O$ among the ten shall choose $4$ mates. This can be done in ${9\choose4}=126$ ways. This gives the team containing $O$. The remaining students form the other team.

Comment: could you explain more

Comment: I want know why is this like c(10,5)\2 could you please explain @Christian Blatter

Comment: what if 2 oldest students each one choose 4 mates